# Azure autoscaling is not working

Tags: azure, hosting, autoscaling

Something is going wrong with Azure. Today autoscaling stopped to work:

[image]

[image]

Maybe anybody knows why it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the images you provided, you have exceeded your CPU threshold for a little over 5 minutes.  It has been my experience that even with a 5 minute evaluation window, it will still take 15-20 minutes (sometimes more) before you see auto-scale actions occur.

According to the [Azure Service Dashboard](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) there are no issues.

So, I would suggest

1. Check your service again after you have 20 minutes worth of data
   (visible on the graph) and see if your service has scaled up.
2. Check the operation logs under Management Services.  If there was a
   failure auto-scaling your service, you would be able to get details there.

Here is a screen-capture reference for #2. Highlight the log you are interested in and click on the Details button at the bottom of your screen.

[image]

Comment: Interesting thing is that it took near 50 minutes before auto-scaling occurred http://www.myimg.us/images/08.21.14/44729.png

Comment: Yep.  *Most* of the time I see it scale in 15-20 minutes.  But, it can take longer.  And by the way, 45 minutes is the default time needed for an auto-scale action to occur for cloud services.  You can change this using the management API's.  I talk about this and how to do it in my blog. http://rickrainey.com/2013/12/15/auto-scaling-cloud-services-on-cpu-percentage-with-the-windows-azure-monitoring-services-management-library/

Comment: Yes, it is a cloud service! Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Average column in the first image, you'll see that while your CPU% is over 50, the Average over one hour is only at 26.47%

In my experience this is the value that Azure will scale on, not the current CPU%.
If after 45 minutes of 1% you suddenly have 99% for 15 minutes, Azure will still not scale.

You can either scale out at lower CPU%, or use Powershell / REST to reduce the 60 minute window over which the average is calculated to something shorter